# Is there a way to control to the initial screenshot shown on Vimeo?

Tags: vimeo

I have uploaded a video to Vimeo. When someone goes to the video page, it is showing some screenshot from the middle of the video. Is there a way to control what is shown when the page is loaded and before the video is played?

Comment: This should be moved to [superuser](http://superuser.com) or [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A litte Googling came back with this [answer:](http://vimeo.com/forums/feature_requests/topic:307) "Go to the video page, then the settings gear icon on the top right, then thumbnails."

Comment: Thanks. I realize my mistake now - I was not logged in and hence didn't see the controls :-(